# Key Error in preprocessing in deep learning model

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning

i'm learning deep learning from kaggle website. I am trying to create neural deep network, but on one of first steps i need to make preprocessing and because of fact that image id and class id are two seperate entities  it makes it easier to split them up in two columns, but got some problem with that.  My code:

```
make_submission = False 
load_pretrained_model = True 
save_model = True 
train_dir = './Desktop/severstal-steel-defect-detection/' 
pretrained_model_path = './Desktop/severstal-pretrained-model/ResUNetSteel_z.h5' 
model_save_path = './ResUNetSteel_w800e50_z.h5' 
train_image_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'train_images') 
train_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(train_dir, 'train.csv')).fillna(-1)


train_df['ImageId'] = train_df['ImageId_ClassId'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
train_df['ClassId'] = train_df['ImageId_ClassId'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])

train_df['ClassId_EncodedPixels'] = train_df.apply(lambda row: (row['ClassId'], row['EncodedPixels']), axis = 1)
grouped_EncodedPixels = train_df.groupby('ImageId')['ClassId_EncodedPixels'].apply(list)
```

After applying that code  im getting that kind of Key Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'ImageId_ClassId'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e1402e10fe66> in <module>
      2 train_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(train_dir, 'train.csv')).fillna(-1)
      3 # image id and class id are two seperate entities and it makes it easier to split them up in two columns
----> 4 train_df['ImageId'] = train_df['ImageId_ClassId'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
      5 train_df['ClassId'] = train_df['ImageId_ClassId'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
      6 # lets create a dict with class id and encoded pixels and group all the defaults per image

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
```

*KeyError: 'ImageId_ClassId'

Does anyone knows how to fix that kind of error and move forward?

train_df.head() gives me that kind of data:
[image]

Comment: I seems like `ImageId_ClassId` is not part of you dataframe, can you show what train_df is. E.g. by train_df.head(), even better might be to attach train.csv

Comment: train_df.head() : 

ImageId ClassId EncodedPixels
0 0002cc93b.jpg 1 29102 12 29346 24 29602 24 29858 24 30114 24 3...
1 0007a71bf.jpg 3 18661 28 18863 82 19091 110 19347 110 19603 11...
2 000a4bcdd.jpg 1 37607 3 37858 8 38108 14 38359 20 38610 25 388...
3 000f6bf48.jpg 4 131973 1 132228 4 132483 6 132738 8 132993 11 ...
4 0014fce06.jpg 3 229501 11 229741 33 229981 55 230221 77 230468...

Comment: added picture to post

Comment: So there is simply no column called `ImageId_ClassId` there is one called ImageId and one called ClassID so what are you trying to achive with this code? `train_df['ImageId'] = train_df['ImageId_ClassId'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])` from my point of view both columns ClassID and ImageID look like they are already correct

Comment: In this kaggle solution there is comment to this code - "image id and class id are two seperate entities and it makes it easier to split them up in two columns". This is what i try to do

Comment: Okay, so I have no idea how the initial csv looks like, but in your dataframe they are already split up into two columns so I would just uncomment the two lines trying to split up the data. Maybe they changed the dataset provided

Comment: hmm, ok. Thanks for help :)